# How to write nested Promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Consider this code where `start`, `continue` and `finish` are promises.

```
export const do = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        start()
            .then(() => continue())
            .then(() => finish())
            .then(() => resolve())
            .catch((reason) => reject(reason))
    });
};
```

Is this how to write nested promises?

Comment: Uhm, yes, that will work. But simply `do  = () => start().then(continue).then(finish)` would work too, since that's already a promise and you don't need a `new Promise`.

Comment: Wouldn't class this as a duplicate personally, but it's relevant: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the whole chain, no need to wrap it:

```
export const _do = () => start()
            .then(continue)
            .then(finish)
;
```